# Handling multiple requests on a TCP/IP Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Is it quite easy to handle multiple requests on a Java TCP / IP socket. Simply accept a message and spawn a thread. Accept another message and spawn another thread.  The thing is once you start spawning threads things get more non deterministic.  Say you have 10 clients and one client keeps firing requests and the other 9 nine who send requests at 10% percent of the hyperactive client, find it harder to get a look in.

One way you could handle this is have a hashmap of semaphores in your server where every client has a corresponding semaphore. Before you handle a request for any client, you could make it go thru its semaphore and configure the semaphores so that each client could only have a certain number of requests at any one time.

At this stage,I'm thinking yeah that works but is there a better way or a library that does this?

Comment: You mean like fair message queue? But I think it would be enough for the Thread to voluntarily go to sleep after every one request, so the others have a fair chance to be woken up and avoid starvation.

Comment: Exactly like a message que. But usually the message goes over a TCP / IP socket before it gets into the Queue. If this socket is multi threaded then you are limited on 'fair' you can be. I think.

Comment: "Other 9 nine who don't fire as much don't get a look in". That doesn't make sense. There is no reason why a multithreaded TCP server would favour one client over another. The whole thing is network-bound anyway. All the threads are initially blocked waiting for incoming requests. If one client sends 10 times the requests of another it will get 10 times the service, but there's no reason why he would get any *more* than 10 times.

Comment: Hi EJP, I have made question clearer.

Comment: thread-per-connection is baby's first networking model. you should look into non blocking io.

Comment: I don't think you've made it clearer at all. I think you've just dreamed up an imaginary problem and are trying to find a solution to it. There are Java servers like Tomcat that are deployed by the million and that handle hundreds of thousands of clients each that don't do anything about this supposed 'problem'. It doesn't exist. A client that is firing 90% of the requests should get 90% of the service. Do you have any evidence at all that it doesn't?

Comment: Ten clients is nothing for any server design.  If one client continually asks for a lot of work, then that is a problem for the server admin and client user - either upgrade the server, charge the client more or some other management mitigation of the issue.  It's got nothing to do with server architecture.

Comment: @Martin James. Ten was just to give an example. Probably not a very good one. Same question for 100,000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but is there a better way ...?

I use one **accepting-thread per serversocket** and a **pool of pre-spawned threads** to handle the workload. The accepting-thread only accepts connections (does nothing else) and gives the handler-socket to one of the threads in the pool. That thread then works with the handler-socket until the client is done, then closes the handler-socket.

You can scale-out this setup as far as you like: If you notice that the accepting-thread is waiting for pool-threads most of the time then you need to x2 your number of pool-threads, if you notice that the accepting-thread is the bottle-neck you create both (A) another accepting-thread and (B) another socket from which it accepts connections and optionally (C) put these on another machine.

The specific problem you are describing with the one *hyper-active* client can be intended/desired if the client is more important than others: in which case you have to do nothing. Or it can be considered a *denial-of-service* attack, in which case you should have a heuristic that just disconnects the client and *temporarily* bans its ip-address.

Comment: Similar to what I had accept you are using a pool for the request processing.  And you don't have anything in the Java layer to check for the DOS. Are you saying this should be done a N/W layer.  Not a bad idea. Just want to know your thinking.

Comment: would you use non blocking i/o and if not why not?

Comment: Whether you do DOS-detection within Java or not is up to you, you CAN do it in Java by just either making the accepting thread look up ip-addresses in a hashmap or letting the worker-threads decide and disconnect. Non-blocking IO: at first i would not bother with it, after all only worker-threads are blocking and you can just add more worker-threads to the pool if all others are blocked. You can later add it but in the beginning i always try to keep things simple and the code linear.